# Angulart ui-router Multiply views and ControllerAs

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-ui-router

Got a problem when using multiple nested views and ControllerAs

Here example of my coffescript and templates

States:

```
  .state "users" ,
    abstract: true,
    url:"/users",
    views:
      "MainLayout":
        templateUrl:"users.html",
  .state "users.add" ,
    url:"/users-add",
    views:
      "ContentLayout":
        templateUrl:"users-add.html",
        controller:"UsersAddController",
        contollerAs:"formctrl",
      "SideLayout":
        templateUrl:"users-side.html",
    cache: false
  .state "users.list" ,
    url:"/users-list",
    views:
      "ContentLayout":
        templateUrl:"users-list.html",
        controller:"UsersController",
        contollerAs:"userlist"
      "SideLayout":
        templateUrl:"users-side.html",
    cache: false
```

users.html

```
<div class="content" ui-view="ContentLayout"></div>
<div class="side" ui-view="SideLayout"></div>
```

users-list.html

```
{{ userlist.result }}
```

users-add.html

```
{{ formctrl.addresult }}
```

users-side.html

```
<menu>
<a ui-sref="users.list">List</a>
<a ui-sref="users.add">Add</a>
</menu>
```

UsersController as sample

```
(->
  UsersController = ()->
    vm = @
    vm.result = "Result"
    return vm
  angular
  .module("myapp")
  .controller("UsersController", UsersController))()
```

This not working at all, but if i make it with $scope, all working normal.What i did wrong?

Comment: why are you returning vm in the controller?

Comment: because without that cotrollerAs syntax will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Sudakatux said in comments there is an [issue on angular-ui-router github](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1880)

Soooo, **i switched to another router** that working normal with Coffee and controllerAs(must return @).

Otherwise, you must refactor your app - use plain js or make it with ng-controller in templates

Answer (score 1):

On the child views you are overriding the parents view so you have to use the @ simbol try this :

```
.state "users.add" ,
    url:"/users-add",
    views:
      "ContentLayout@":
        templateUrl:"users-add.html",
        controller:"UsersAddController",
        contollerAs:"formctrl",
      "SideLayout@":
        templateUrl:"users-side.html",
    cache: false
  .state "users.list" ,
    url:"/users-list",
    views:
      "ContentLayout@":
        templateUrl:"users-list.html",
        controller:"UsersController",
        contollerAs:"userlist"
      "SideLayout@":
        templateUrl:"users-side.html",
```

Ok so now that i see your plunker, since you are using ui-views inside ui-views, you have to include what to ovrwride or target :

```
state "users.add" ,
    url:"/users-add",
    views:
      "ContentLayout@users":
        templateUrl:"users-add.html",
        controller:"UsersAddController",
        contollerAs:"formctrl",
      "SideLayout@users":
        templateUrl:"users-side.html",
  .state "users.list" ,
    url:"/users-list",
    views:
      "ContentLayout@users":
        templateUrl:"users-list.html",
        controller:"UsersController",
        contollerAs:"userlist"
      "SideLayout@users":
        templateUrl:"users-side.html",
```

So im targeting the ContentLayout '@' AT the users state.

here is your fixed plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/vPdjntVJn9dVE9Y7mkm3?p=preview

Hope it helps

Comment: Not helped me at all.Blank page.Smth wrong and i can't solve this problem about 2 days :( I tried a lot of combinations

Comment: Could you post the whole config with the @ symbols placed. If you can put a plunker that would be great

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/2WwcWOKoej7LExn8yWrh without @, and it's half working. You can make it with @, and nothing will work ( i think i create it right on plunker)

Comment: Fixed?I think it fixed when i get "Hello World" and "Fizz Buzz" at diff states.I can see only Hello and 
Fizz {{ formctrl.addresult }} .Something went wrong again :(

Comment: changing states worked at the first time already.The main problem that Multiply views and ControllerAs syntax not working, i can't work with vm = @ and set vm.var  . How can i replace my example using clasess, i can't find simple sample for my  case.

Comment: After trying different thing found this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1880